# Ray Tracer Uniform Grid Traversal in OpenCL

Tags: raytracing

I'm attempting to create a Real Time Ray Tracer using OpenCL however, I'm very new to OpenCL and how to use it.

As part of accelerating the ray tracing process, I have implemented a Uniform Grid which can be traversed via a form of the DDA algorithm seen here: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf

My problem is, although I can traverse the grid and grab the cells to check for objects, I am unable to actually access those objects (it sends the kernel build in to an endless loop). They exist in the array but I believe it is due to the way the GPU inlines the commands that it can't resolve the program.

The following is the piece of code that is having trouble, where 'grid' is a 4D array represented as a 1D (fourth dimension for holding each object in a cell), toAccess is the list of elements containing object IDs that were encountered during grid traversal, caughtObjs is the size of toAccess (amount of objects encountered) and objList is the list of object IDs I'm trying to get.

```
for(int i = 0; i < caughtObjs; i++){
     objList[i] = grid[toAccess[i]]; //Commenting out this line stops the build crash
}
```

So I'm assuming using an array to reference elements in another array is bad in OpenCL due to its inlining. So what is a common alternative used to combat this problem?

(Also, I'm aware you're meant to check one cell at a time but I'm not doing this because the depth of the loops required was killing OpenCL's build too.)

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. More code, less text.